# Use GenericRepository with include and an expression - C#

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement the generic repository pattern.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllIncludingAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<object, bool>>[] includes, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<T?> GetIncludingAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

And this is the class that implements the interface

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;
    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _entitySet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllIncludingAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<object, bool>>[] includes, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    foreach (var item in includes)
    {
        query = (IQueryable<T>)query.Include(item);
    }
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

  public async Task<T?> GetIncludingAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    foreach (var item in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(item);
    }
    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(expression);
}
}
```

So far so good. But when I want to use the Repository in my service I don't know what to do.

```
IEnumerable<Booking>? bookings = await _unitOfWork
.BookingRepository
.GetAllIncludingAsync(x => x.Id == personId, y => y.Inc); //here I want to include Person
```

Don't know how I can use the method from the repository.

The BookingRepository is just a repository that implements the GenericRepository

Comment: Your Booking Entity should have a Person {get;set; } field. Then you use lambda =>
.GetAllIncludingAsync(x => x.Id == personId, y => y.Person);

Comment: @firatt_ that doesn't work

Comment: Why do you want this? A DbSet is already a generic single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a generic multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library, that's ADO.NET's job. The methods you posted simply rename the methods of DbContext while leaking the implementation into the caller. For example, `Include` is only used to eagerly load related entities, *not* for implementing JOINS. No caller of any "repository" class should care if entities are loaded eagerly or explicitly, only that they *are* loaded

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter method like this:

```
Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includes
```

And you will be able to call it like this:

```
GetAllIncludingAsync(x => x.Id == personId,x => x.Include(y => y.Person).Include(y => y.OtherTable))
```

Comment: And if I want to use more than just one

Comment: I can't use include there as includes is not a property of Booking. Furthermore, I think it would still fail beacuse the code in the GenericRepository class also needs to be refactored